# Python @property for editing a config file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Would it be pythonic to use @property / @variable.setter for getting/setting entries from/in a config file? For example the file could be xml, yaml, etc. and I might want to write:

```
config_file.port = 80
```

Comment: It is part of the language, it is up to you to decide whether to use it or not.  Does it fit your needs?  What is `pythonesque` - sounds a bit subjective to me.

Answer (score 0):

Python manual states:

> The structure of `INI` files is described in the following section.
>   Essentially, the file consists of sections, each of which contains
>   keys with values. `configparser` classes can read and write such files.
>   Let’s start by creating the above configuration file programmatically.

Add values to `configparse`:

```
>>> import configparser
>>> config = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> config['DEFAULT'] = {'ServerAliveInterval': '45',
...                      'Compression': 'yes',
...                      'CompressionLevel': '9'}
>>> config['bitbucket.org'] = {}
>>> config['bitbucket.org']['User'] = 'hg'
>>> config['topsecret.server.com'] = {}
>>> topsecret = config['topsecret.server.com']
>>> topsecret['Port'] = '50022'     # mutates the parser
>>> topsecret['ForwardX11'] = 'no'  # same here
>>> config['DEFAULT']['ForwardX11'] = 'yes'
>>> with open('example.ini', 'w') as configfile:
...   config.write(configfile)
```

Retrieve values from `configparse`:

```
>>> config = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.sections()
[]
>>> config.read('example.ini')
['example.ini']
>>> config.sections()
['bitbucket.org', 'topsecret.server.com']
>>> 'bitbucket.org' in config
True
>>> 'bytebong.com' in config
False
>>> config['bitbucket.org']['User']
'hg'
>>> config['DEFAULT']['Compression']
'yes'
>>> topsecret = config['topsecret.server.com']
>>> topsecret['ForwardX11']
'no'
>>> topsecret['Port']
'50022'
>>> for key in config['bitbucket.org']:  
...     print(key)
user
compressionlevel
serveraliveinterval
compression
forwardx11
>>> conf
```

Comment: I'll certainly check out configparser, but I should have given more detail. I'm actually writing test automation to test a Windows service that was written in C#. Config files are already given to me. I want to set various values in order to test various cases. While I've used the decorator to set attributes in other parts of the code, I have these set methods that set configs (i.e. write to file). And I just thought ah, I could use @property for this.